# Limits questions confusion

Tags: limits

> Evaluate the limit of this as $n$ tends to infinity of
>   $$\left(\frac{n}{n+100}\right)^{2n}.$$

If you divide top and bottom by n the bit in the brackets would be $\frac{1}{1+\frac{100}{n}}$ which tends to $1$ as $n$ tends to infinity so the limit should be 1? however if you input values for $1,2,3,\dots$ you can see the sequence getting smaller and away from 1. Why is that?

Comment: It takes the form $1^{+\infty}$ but it does not mean that the limit is 1.

Comment: You disregard the exponent, which goes increasing and counteracts the increase of $1/(1+100/n)<1$.

Comment: Ans is $e^{-200}$.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use the property that the limit of a product is the product of the limits. But this property holds when the number of factors is fixed which is not the case.

Note that
$$\left(\frac{n}{n+100}\right)^{2n}=\left(\left(1+\frac{100}{n}\right)^{n}\right)^{-2}.$$
Recall that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{a}{n}\right)^{n}=e^a$.
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Let $$a_n=\left(\frac{n}{n+100}\right)^{2n}$$
As you mentioned, we have that:
$$a_n=\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{100}{n}}\right)^{2n}$$
Alternatively, one can write this as follows:
$$a_n=\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{200}{2n}}\right)^{2n}$$
We know that the sequence:
$$\gamma_n=\left(1+\frac{c}{n}\right)^{n},\ c\in\mathbb{R}$$
converges to $e^c$. For $c=200$, we have that:
$$\gamma_n=\left(1+\frac{200}{n}\right)^n$$
So
$$\frac{1}{\gamma_n}=\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{200}{n}}\right)^n\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\frac{1}{e^{200}}$$
Finally, note that:
$$a_n=\frac{1}{\gamma_{2n}}$$
so $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=e^{-200}$$
as the limit of a subsequence of a convergent sequence.

Answer (score 0):

it is equivalent to $$\left(\left(1-\frac{100}{n+100}\right)^{(n+100)/100}\right)^{200n/(n+100)}$$ and the Limit is given by $$\frac{1}{e^{100}}$$

Comment: Well the limit is $1/e^{200}$.

Comment: this is right it follows from my term above